# Java and error in Cast programming--AttrCertExample?

Tags: java, bouncycastle

When i run my program, the console gives me an error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/x509/examples/AttrCertExample

What's my problem?

Comment: You miss the `com.springsource.org.bouncycastle.jce.jar` in your classpath

Comment: No, here is my declaration into .classpath file :
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="...../com.springsource.org.bouncycastle.jce-1.46.0.jar"/>

Comment: You run it from eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure that your classpath is set up correctly? The error means that Java can't find the .class file for that class. This [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) explains more about the classpath. If you're using Eclipse, you can click on your project in the project tree and go to File->Properties->Java Build Path to edit the paths.

Comment: The directions are the same with MyEclipse. Once you go to Java Build Path, go to libraries, and Add External JARs... Find all the bouncycastle JARs and open them to add them to the classpath.

Comment: Even that configuration of the path, the error still the same

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Java Build Path settings?

Comment: sorry, i have tryed to post it but my reputation is under 10. So impossible to do it

Comment: Are you running the program in a servlet container like Tomcat?